# Is CRC32 really so bad for file integrity check?

Tags: file, crc32, integrity

Of course that MD5 is better then CRC32, SHA1 is better then MD5 and so on... But also they are also much slower then CRC32.

Right know, I am thinking about how to check consistency of being transfered file and CRC32 is fastest option.

I haven't found anywhere **how bad is CRC32 for integrity checks** (maybe in other words how is probably that CRC32 will not detect malformed file)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quoting from http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath458.htm :

> So, if we assume that any corruption of our data affects our string 
>   in a completely random way, i.e., such that the corrupted string  is
>   totally uncorrelated with the original string, then **the  probability
>   of a corrupted string going undetected is 1/(2^n)**.  This is the basis
>   on which people say a 16-bit CRC has a probability of 1/(2^16) =
>   1.5E-5 of failing to detect an error in the data,  and a **32-bit CRC has a probability of 1/(2^32), which is about 
>   2.3E-10 (less than one in a billion)**.

My opinion: CRC-32 is more than enough for error detection. It is being used widely. However, it is not secure when you want to use it as a "hash function".

Answer (score 1):

Collisions (same hash output but different data) can occur easily using CRC-32 because CRC-32 use only 32bits compare to other algorithms ex. MD5 is 128-bits, SHA-1 is 160-bits, SHA-2 (SHA256/512 series) is 224bits-512bits. (depend on what you use). Also, for SHA-2 series no collision has been found.

For more info about mathematics and probability that would cause your data a collision. Please look for [Hash Collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision) and [Birthday paradox problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)